# Acessing directive's scope within trancluded ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm writing a component and need to ng-repeat on directive's isolate scope property.

Consider this:

```
<div some-directive>
    <h2>Let's repeat something</h2>
    <p ng-repeat="item in contr.items">
      Title: {{ item.title }} 
      Description: {{ item.desc }}
    </p>
</div>
```

My idea is that directive provides a collection of items (a resolve in real code, but I will keep it simple here). Right now I have:

```
.directive('someDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.items = this.items = [{
        title: "Item 1 title",
        desc: "Description"
      }, {
        title: "Item 2 title",
        desc: "Another desc"
      }, {
        title: "Item 3 title",
        desc: "Third desc"
      }, {
        title: "Item 4 title",
        desc: "Third desc"
      }];
    },
    controllerAs: 'contr'
  };
});
```

See [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GEGfDbUmbpYFyWWJeN2d?p=preview%20this%20Plunkr) (and edit if you like).

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design that content added via `ng-transclude` will be binded with an outer (original) scope, not a scope of the current element that `ng-transclude` is on.

If you want the transcluded content to be binded with the isolate scope, you could use a modified version of `ng-tranclude` like this:

```
.directive('myTransclude', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers, transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(scope, function(nodes) {
        element.empty();
        element.append(nodes);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

and use it instead of `ng-tranclude` like this:

```
template: '<div my-transclude></div>',
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/yDwuwCYtAzxyIhJRgZoJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I'm sure I knew this transclude behaviour before though :) I ended up using myTransclude as you suggested. (that's a neat trick)